# How to add code-behind code to umbraco templates?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, content-management-system, umbraco

I am getting started with umbraco 4.5.2.
I have my site up and running, and I am designing templates using some ASP.NET controls. How can I respond to events from these controls?

For example, I have added a Button to a template. How can I edit the code-behind file to perform some action whenever the button is clicked?

Thank you,

Martin Wiboe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the bottom of this [blog post](http://www.kipusoep.nl/2010/07/23/umbraco-45-visual-studio-2010-dotless-jquery-vsdoc-squishit-masterpages/).

Quote:

> When using Visual Studio, it’s nice to have code-behind files for your templates (at least, that’s how we do stuff). If you create a template in Umbraco, it creates a masterpage without code-behind…
>
> Then you would have to add a code-behind manually, link it with the mark-up and create designer file. That sucks right?
>
> Just do this:
>
> 1. Create a nested masterpage in VS and use your ‘master’-masterpage as masterpage in the masterpages folder. Lol, there’s a lot of ‘masterpage’ in that sentence hehe.
>    VS creates a masterpage for you with code-behind, sweet!
> 2. VS opens the mark-up of this newly created masterpage, keep it opened!
> 3. Then go to your Umbraco back-end and create a template like you would normally do.
> 4. Give it the same name as you defined in step 1.
> 5. This should create an Umbraco template by using the already created masterpage as file.
> 6. Now return to Visual Studio. It should notify you that the file has changed and gives you the option to reload the file. Reload and then use CTRL+Z to undo the changes made by Umbraco (else the code-behind won’t be linked to the mark-up) and save it.
> 7. You’re done!

Comment: Link is dead, please post something that explains the answer.

Comment: @MarcUberstein Updated link and quoted the blog post just in case it changes again.

Answer (score 5):

You can actually create fully functional ASP.NET `.ascx` Controls, and wrap them in a Macro to display inside your template/page.

Check out this [excellent video](http://umbraco.org/documentation/videos/for-developers/foundation/using-net-user-controls) on how to do this.

Good luck!

Marko

Answer (score 0):

There is also this utility that will create the codefiles for you http://umbracocs.codeplex.com/